# Android studio doesn't generate layout preview when custom views with databinding are used

Tags: android, android-studio, android-custom-view, android-xml, android-databinding

```
class SimpleView @JvmOverloads constructor( context: Context,
    attrs: AttributeSet? = null,
    defStyleAttr: Int = 0
) : ConstraintLayout(context, attrs, defStyleAttr) {

    init {
        val inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context)
        SimpleViewBinding.inflate(inflater, this, true)
    }
     fun setObjData(uiState: UiState<ExampleData>) {
        if (uiState is UiState.Data) {
            binding.obj = uiState.data
        }
    }
}
```

corresponding layout: simple_view.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <data>

        <variable
            name="obj"
            type="com.project.example.model.dataObject" />
    </data>

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/abcid"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@{obj.title}"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_20sp"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            tools:text="Test" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</layout>
```

usage in other layouts as below, however this other layout (where simpleView is used) doesn't generate preview.

```
   <androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical">


              <com.project.example.view.SimpleView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    app:ObjData="{@viewmodel.obj}"/>
```

**NOTE:** Preview is generated only when databinding `android:text="@{obj.text}"`  is **not** used in simple_view.xml

Answer (score 1):

Preview seems to work fine on `Chipmunk | 2021.2.1`,
while on new `Dolphin` and higher version, it does not work.

https://developer.android.com/studio/archive

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).